What is our feelings and emotions?
are we really free or are a simulation being run by a higher body which runs are feelings thoughts and emotions. .  These are some common questions which i ponder upon and think in my free time. (I am not depressed but I would like the idea of what u all think)

The original question: What is the true purpose of life?
The purpose of (man's) life can only be defined in relation to something and therefore depends on metaphysical assumptions.
For example, I can say the purpose of a tree is to provide material, shade and oxygen for men, only after I have assumed trees were made for men. This is Aristotelian teleology which Christianity has adopted.
So, the Christian answer, which could be found in any older catechism among the first few questions states: The purpose of life is to know, love and serve God and in that way to attain Heaven.
Because God is the most perfect good, and our Creator, it is only just and reasonable to direct ourselves toward Him. It would be irrational to put something imperfect above God.
A Christian's final end, therefore, is union with God in Heaven, seeing Him as He really is, not as through a mirror, as in this life, but face to face.
The means to attaining Heaven are given in a specific order because by knowing God more intimately one naturally comes to love Him and, by loving Him, one naturally wants to serve Him.
Much more could be said, but that is the crux of it.

Should I delete my answer if it's no longer relevant? Is it allowed to completely change the question?

While the OPer can change the question, it is very much discouraged and frowned upon to change it in such a way that renders answers already posted irrelevant. Question is closed and probably won't be reopened so no real risk of letting your answer remain here (unless it gets down-voted).

@Hokon Thank you.
